# How to block and wait the result of an async function in a non-async function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Very simple code:

```
async def poll():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def caller(somefunction):
    somefunction() # we don't know if callable is async or not

def main():
    caller(poll) # how to pass an async function "poll" here?
```

I want to call "poll" by passing it as a callable/lambda to "caller" function. Normally, in a well designed language, e.g. C# you'd do `poll().Result` because poll() returns a Task which has methods like Wait() and Result to block and wait OR you can use "await" if you want to block and wait AND return to the caller of the current async method you're in.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring a `async` function and then calling it, also requires to wait for it. Like with the `await asyncio.sleep(1)`, you need to await the `callee()`. See below:

```py
import asyncio

async def callee():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print ("first")
    return 1


async def caller():
    await callee() # how do I wait the result of this?
    print("second")


async def main():
    await caller()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**--EDIT--**

To run a coroutine you have 3 options in `asyncio`.

1. The asyncio.run() function: which can't be used here because there can only be 1 event loop run at the same time.
2. `await` the coroutine: which you don't want/can't in a sync function
3. With `asyncio.create_task()`: which needs to be awaited too somewhere in your code

When you dont't await option 2 and 3, the coroutine simply won't execute. So what you are trying to do here can't be achieved with the `asyncio` package.

What I don't really understand is why you want to execute an `async` function to wait for it in sync? That defeats the purpose of using tasks..

Comment: You made "caller" async. My question is about how to wait in a non-async function

Comment: I chaned my answer to reflect your changes, but what you want to do can't be done in `asyncio`

Comment: Thank you, let me try to explain why I need this. I'm editing my question

Comment: I can't really see a solution here, I don't know the `rx` package and it's capabilities. I hope someone is able to solve it for you.

Comment: it's not really about rx, you can imagine any other situation where you are passing in a function as a parameter and you want to pass an async function

Comment: I've edited my question again to get rid of RX

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by separating your code into two tasks. One task runs the asyncio event loop while the other task executes the synchronous part of the code. The synchronous code can then wrap the coroutine to be dispatched in the event loop via [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading) and block until the result is available.

```
import asyncio

async def poll():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

def caller(somefunction):
    somefunction() # we don't know if callable is async or not

loop = None

def coroutine_wrapper(coro):
    def fun():
        # Shedule the coroutine in the event loop of the main thread
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(coro(), loop)
        # Wait for the result, this is blocking and may not be done in the
        # thread of the event loop:
        return future.result()
    return fun

def sync_main():
    caller(coroutine_wrapper(poll))

async def async_main():
    global loop
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    # dispatch the sync method to a new thread to keep sync and async parts of
    # the program seperate
    await asyncio.to_thread(sync_main)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run the event loop in the main thread
    asyncio.run(async_main())
```

But why do we need two threads? Asyncio is a form of cooperative multitasking with the goal to make possible points of task switching explicit. Allowing async callbacks from non async methods would be problematic: This would allow a task switch in a part of the code that assumes to have no task switching.